# Wordpress Action Scheduler not running

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, action-scheduler

I am trying to learn how to use the action scheduler so I am hoping somehow can give me some good pointers. I've got this code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wootomation_schedule' );
add_action( 'wootomation_import', 'wootomation_do_action' );

function wootomation_schedule() {
    // if ( false === as_next_scheduled_action( 'wootomation_import' ) ) {
    //  as_schedule_recurring_action( time(), 30, 'wootomation_import' );
    // }
    if ( false === as_next_scheduled_action( 'wootomation_import' ) ) {
        as_enqueue_async_action( 'wootomation_import' );
    }
}

function wootomation_do_action() {
    var_dump('test');
    wp_mail( 'hello@wpharvest.com', 'test AS', 'Action schedule completed' );
}
```

Which appears to create the action but it never runs. I tried refreshing the front end of the website but didn't help.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to get it to run?

And the 2nd question would be, is this the right approach for breaking up some heavy indexing, maybe with args such as page: "0-100", page: "101-200", etc.

Thanks, Dragos

Comment: Is that php code above part of a class?

Comment: Ah yes, I've simplified it now, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I've added the woocommerce tag, because it looks like this issue has to do with hooks specific to that plugin. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's fine, I'm building an extension for WooCommerce, but the Action Scheduler can be used as a library on its own, on any (WordPress) project.

Comment: I have installed and enabled the last version of [action-scheduler-3.1.6.zip](https://github.com/woocommerce/action-scheduler/releases) plugin and tested your code…It works: The event is sheduled slowly few minutes later (I have received the email)... Now I have removed `var_dump('test');` as this is a background process.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, it seemed the issue was with Local by Flywheel for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, after all, the issue was with my Local by Flywheel which seems to not support `wp_cron` for some reason... I've tested it on a live server and it works.

Thanks @LoicTheAztec for testing and confirming.